# How to implement an audit interceptor in jdbi?

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor, audit, jdbi

Is there a way to implement the Audit Interceptor concept from Hibernate in JDBI ?
[Audit Interceptor example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)

Answer (score 2):

[Audit4j](http://audit4j.org) contains the built-in AOP interceptor with annotation support through Spring plugin.

Yet you can use the Hibernate interceptor as a plugin for Audit4j core. Audit4j DB plugin supports to store audit trails in to database with different configuration options.